# Send email automatically based on its status when a certain cell is edit or fill-up

Tags: android

As you can see I have a status on the left and and date completed on the most right:

[image]

What I want to achieve is when the date completed have been fill-up it will send an email to a certain person containing the status as the subject and all other info's on that column.

Answer (score 0):

based on your question, i google and come across this solution [Sending Emails without User Intervention (no Intents) in Android](http://www.jondev.net/articles/Sending_Emails_without_User_Intervention_%28no_Intents%29_in_Android)